# PYQT5 How to access content layou that is inside another layout (sub layout)

Tags: python, pyqt5

[Here I took part of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930677/how-to-use-qscrollarea-for-one-or-many-qgroupbox/69571112#69571112)

Part of my code:

```py
    def add_SP(self):

        self.layout_SArea_SP.addWidget(self.createLayout_groupbox_SP(self.layout_SArea_SP.count()+1))

    def dell_ports(self):
        import sip
        if self.layout_SArea_SP.count() > 0: sip.delete(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(self.layout_SArea_SP.count()-1).widget())

    def createLayout_groupbox_SP(self, number):
        self.groupbox_SP = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Port-{}:".format(number), self)
        self.layout_in_groupbox_SP = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.groupbox_SP)
        self.combobox_type_ports = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupbox_SP)
        self.combobox_type_ports.addItems(list_type_ports)
        self.num_SP = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupbox_SP)
        self.num_SP.setFixedSize(20,20)
        self.name_port = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupbox_SP)
        self.unagged_vlan = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupbox_SP)
        self.tagget_vlan = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupbox_SP)        
        self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.addWidget(self.combobox_type_ports)
        self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.addWidget(self.num_SP)
        self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.addWidget(self.name_port)
        self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.addWidget(self.unagged_vlan)
        self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.addWidget(self.tagget_vlan)
        return self.groupbox_SP

    def exemple_commands():
        print(self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.itemAt(0).widget().currentText())
        print(self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.itemAt(1).widget().text())
        print(self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.itemAt(2).widget().text())
        print(self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.itemAt(3).widget().text())
```

When I run the function exemple_commands()
I get the data of the last created layout_in_groupbox_SP.
How do i refer to the previous items layout_in_groupbox_SP?
That is, I need to address something like this:

```
self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(0)/self.groupbox_SP/self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.itemAt(0)
or 
self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(X)/self.groupbox_SP/self.layout_in_groupbox_SP.itemAt(X)
```

How can i do this?

Comment: First group-box: `gb = self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(0).widget()`; first group-box child: `c = gb.layout().itemAt(0).widget()`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion in the comments, I was able to implement the following:

```
def exemple_commands(): 
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(0).widget().layout().itemAt(0).widget().currentText())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(0).widget().layout().itemAt(1).widget().text())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(0).widget().layout().itemAt(2).widget().text())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(0).widget().layout().itemAt(3).widget().text())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(1).widget().layout().itemAt(0).widget().currentText())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(1).widget().layout().itemAt(1).widget().text())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(1).widget().layout().itemAt(2).widget().text())
    print(self.layout_SArea_SP.itemAt(1).widget().layout().itemAt(3).widget().text())
```